# WSO2 Identity / Setup of Federated Authentication using SAML

Tags: wso2, identity, saml, wso2-identity-server

The basic topology is like this: 
 WSO2 IS as my service provider and takes care of authorization via XACML, our existing internal IdP takes care of corporate authentication (SAML, Oauth2).

I'd like to receive a guidance about best practice how to configure an outbound Federation using the WSO2 IS as a proxy for SAML protocol. Is it correct to separate the user ID domain, by creating so a called "tenant" in order to route the SAML requests though an outgoing STS connection to an external primary IdP?  Is this configured under Identity Provider - add Identity Provider - Federated Authenticators - WS Federation Passive Configuration?

Domains and Tenants?
As an example, I would like to configure an account like this. ID = falb@red.com, where the federated lookup will forward my request to the IdP responsible for the domain "@red.com". Is there any discovery, or smart routing mechanism available that is able to identify the "red.com" domain, without need of creating a tenant?

XACML Access?
In a more advanced scenario, once we have a federation between the WSO2 server and and external IDP, is a service provider, a web application server, able to dispatch a PEP request by attaching a SAML token, without use of preceding entitlement routines, like passage of login and password. Is there an entitlement routine in place that accepts SAML tokens at the PDP side and validates it though the SSO federation mechanism?

Thanks in advance for your guidance. 
Regards
Claude

Comment: I would split your post into two questions, Claude...

Comment: Dear David, I understand your comments asking to split the question, thanks. Although we have to consider that there might exist different topologies and server grouping, so the second part of the question
relates to the configuration described in the first section of the question. As we live in corporations we often have to build our solution design over an existing infrastructure structures like domains, IdP, SAML, or extending it with new functions, like in our case, the use of XACML technology. If possible, please scope this as a design question followed by an implementation question.